# Mock static getter with jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a logging service that have static getters.

```
  static get error(): Function {
    return console.error.bind(console, 'Error: ');
  }
```

Tried with:
    `jest.spyOn(ConsoleLoggingService, 'error').mockImplementation(() => 'blah');`

but I get `TypeError: Cannot set property info of function ConsoleLoggingService() {} which has only a getter`

Also tried:
    `jest.spyOn(ConsoleLoggingService, 'error', 'get').mockImplementation(() => 'blah');`
And get `TypeError: console_logging_service_1.ConsoleLoggingService.error is not a function`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why does it need to be an accessor? Can `ConsoleLoggingService.error` be a function directly?

Comment: @PedroMutter Yes I believe this is over-complicated but I'm trying to avoid modify the code (that is working) to perform the unit testing.

Comment: I see... You can try to mock the whole file `jest.mock('path/to/ConsoleLoggingService')` . And them import it and change the value of `error` in the `beforeAll` hook. Like `ConsoleLoggingService.error = jest.fn()`

Comment: Not working. I get a TS error `Cannot assign to 'error' because it is a read-only property`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jest.spyOn(ConsoleLoggingService, 'error', 'get').mockImplementation(() => ...)` mocks `get` accessor function, so an implementation is expected to return another function, while a string is returned.

It can return another spy for testing purposes:

```
jest.spyOn(ConsoleLoggingService, 'error', 'get').mockReturnValue(jest.fn())
...
expect(ConsoleLoggingService.error).toBeCalledWith(...)
```

The use of `get` is less efficient because the function is bound on every `error` access. It could be simplified to:

```
static error = console.error.bind(console, 'Error: ')
```

And mocked as:

```
jest.spyOn(ConsoleLoggingService, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {})
```